# Animation for moving an ImageView up and down

Tags: android, animation, move

I am new to Animation in Android and searched a lot about Move up and Down an ImageView, but there are lot tuts about move left to right. I can't find a tut to move up and Down. Can please anyone tell me how can I achieve this?
I am adding some code here, that I have learned from YouTube to move an image left to right(imga is ImageView) -

```
 Animation img = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.ABSOLUTE, 150, Animation.ABSOLUTE, Animation.ABSOLUTE);
            img.setDuration(3000);
            img.setFillAfter(true);

            imga.startAnimation(img);
```

Comment: What is the difference with up and down. Please specify your question.

Comment: So, @julien-100000, now I want to make an app that has an image(ball). What I am trying to do is when we click on that image, the ball will go up. and after that when we click again, it will revert back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this xml for animation
**anim/up_down.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" >


<!-- Move -->

<translate
    android:duration="800"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:toYDelta="70%p" />

<translate
    android:duration="800"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:startOffset="800"
    android:toYDelta="-70%p" />


</set>
```

In Java Class:

```
// Animation
Animation animUpDown;

 // load the animation
animUpDown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
            R.anim.up_dwon);

  // start the animation
  view.startAnimation(animUpDown);
```

Comment: Thank you Bro, I just got your Answer and translated to my version. Thanks a Lot.

Answer (score 3):

You need to know the logic behind movement of image or object that will animate in the axis from x to x delta or from y to y delta where

- Values in x=n variable to x= -n variable depict that image will move
  from right to left delta
- Values in  x= -n variable to x=n variable depict that image will move
  from left to right delta
- Values in  y=n variable to y=-n variable depict that image will move 
  from top to bottom delta
- Values in  y=-n variable to y=n variable depict that image will move 
  from bottom to top delta

Below image will take you to the 10 standard Mathematics
[image: movement graph for the image]

**Note: Here n is considered the DP or point of the vertices.**

Comment: Thanks to you too, your post showed me about axis and vertices.